# The points go to the zero

Tags: c++, c++-cli

The problem in build graph.
I use the TChart(Microsoft Visual Studio 2012).
Code,where I build my graph

```
for(int j = 0;j<Nt-1;j++)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<Nx;i++)
    {                 
        chart2->Series["Series1"]->BorderWidth=3;
        chart2->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(i,wht[j][i]);
    }
}
```

This graph
[image]

The points go to the zero,but the right solve is the lines continued and ended in their line(without zeros)

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Your `for` loops are not in a function.

Comment: @mch in this loop `for` (when building a graph) already contains the array with results of function. This array is  `wht[j][i]`

Comment: What is your actual question here? Is it about calculating your 2D array, or graphing that 2D array? If it's about calculating the array, add the missing methods & constants to your calculation code, and show us the expected & actual resulting numeric values. If it's about graphing the results, remove all the calculation stuff, and show us the data & the function to graph it only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chart2->Series["Series1"]->Points->AddXY(i,wht[j][i]);
```

You only have one chart series, and that series has the first set of results (`j==0`), followed by the second set, (`j==1`), followed by the third, etc. So the points graphed look like this:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(2, 0)
(3, 0)
(4, 3)
(5, 3)
(6, 3)
(7, 3)
(8, 3)
(0, 0)
etc...
(8, 2.9)
(0, 0)
etc...
```

So, look what happens after the first set: The last point in set 1 is `(8, 3)`, and the next point you tell it to graph is `(0, 0)`. And it draws a line from one point to the next.

What you need to do is set up your chart with multiple series, and use a new series for each set of data. Perhaps that would look something like this:

```
chart2->Series["Series" + (j+1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(i,wht[j][i]);
```